# Is it possible to press the keypad of an ongoing phone call in android

Tags: android, kotlin

I am new to android development and I wanted to know if it is possible to press numbers on keypad of an ongoing phone call?

I read that you can open dialer keypad using this code:

```kotlin
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL)
intent.data = Uri.parse("tel:123 456789")
startActivity(intent)
```

But my intention is to access the dialer inside an active phone call, so this does not answer my needs.

Image for clarification regarding the keypad I am referring to:

[image: phone call keytab]

Comment: How do you initiate the call ? By manually or by  ACTION DIAL intent ??

Comment: manual call - regular call that the user makes

Comment: Then, it is not possible as there is no way to detect when the call is connected at the moment in Android. But, if you can change the call initiation from manual to ACTION_DIAL, then you can use DTMF for above purpose.\

Comment: Thank you very much, can you explain how you can achieve that?

Comment: At what time do you need to press the keys?  right after the call got answered??

Comment: Yes, it needs to be after the call got answered. it doesn't have to be right away though